# Ubuntu gnome terminal freeze

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm a bit new to linux. using Ubuntu-16.04LTS.
The terminal froze when i trip to open browser using terminal command.
Browser name website
(chromium-browser www.facebook.com)
Terminal resumed after closing the browser 
Is there anything I need to know?

Comment: This is normal.

Comment: Yes, anything that you run from a terminal window (including GUI apps), will exclusively use that terminal until you close them. You can append `&` after the command to run it in the background, thus letting you use the terminal. `chromium-browser www.facebook.com &`.

Comment: @JonasCz  so can the website be used via commands? Like login or message via terminal?

Comment: No, chrome(ium) does not support that.

Comment: So does any other browser supports? Can you recommend me to a website or article , where i can find how to operate this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes .. That's the way it works. As long as a command is running in the terminal, it is blocked from doing other things. Think of chromium-browser as a long running process, just as `sleep 60` or similar.

You can put it in the background, freeing your terminal prompt for other work, either by pressing `ctrl-z` to suspend the process, and then type `bg %1` (or the number ctrl-z returned in [] if not 1) to let it run in background.

Or adding a `&` after the command when you start it:

```
sleep 60 &
```

This will send it in the background immediately.